# Dynamic Content Control in Extlib flips out after rebuild

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an issue with the dynamic content control in ExtLib. Every time I compile my xpage the dynamic content control flips out if I do not reload the page. I need a way to control this, like an onerror event on the control.

this is wahat's happening

1. I open my webpage, the dynamic content control works fine
2. I do some changes to my xpages and build (webpage still open)
3. I click a link on my webpage to reload the content in the dynamic content control.
4. the webpage flips out and starts to reload constantly using a partial refresh url.

I use various ways to update this control. sometimes it is through a csjs link and somtimes it is per interval using XSP.partialRefreshGet() so I guess I need a way to know if the dynamic content control is available before calling it, or let the control notify me somehow that is is not available

any idea?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change an XPage you must do a manual full reload of that page in any browser. Executing any call from the stale page will not work.