# xPages making continues requests to the server after rebuild

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a problem with xPages after rebuild, if a user tries to access a page after a rebuild the webpage starts to make continues requests to server, The application uses extlib and the dyamic content control.

The big problem here is that if you are making interval ajax request in the webpage, the same problem will happend without user actions. So all users having the webpage open after a new design is added will automatically get this problem which could probably kill the server.

I am not sure, but I think this might be a Extension Library problem

There is a youtube video of the problem here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y15XLtWsq80&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thomas, this question sounds like a duplicate of one of your other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154391/dynamic-content-control-in-extlib-flips-out-after-rebuild :-)

Comment: Well. Yes...forgot about that. :-) doesn't hurt to take this another round as I think this problem need a better solution